# Post handler doesn't parse serialized form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I've read a lot of tutorials across the internet about handling form values which are passed to POST handler via AJAX call.
All of them assume, that *serialized* form is parsed by Handler method without any problems. Unfortunately, in my case something went wrong, and I can't get correct values from my *serialized* form.

Following images present post handler, html for form and ajax call.

I would like to mention few additional things.
First of all, according to tutorials I'd like to encapsulate form fields in separate class, in this case *ResponseModel*. Anyway, I was not able to retrieve any value from the serialized form passed as an ajax argument. It looks like form is serialized, cause I can see correct value when I log *serializedForm* variable.

When I change argument type for *response* argument from *ResponseModel* to simple string then string is passed to handler, and I can retrieve this value as a string, but not as an object (that's what I expect). Just can't understand why it works without any issues in all theses tutorials, and I can't implement this in my own project.

So my question - ***Why post handler can't parse serialized form into expected object?***

Many thanks

ResponseModel class:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Property for the input fields:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public ResponseModel EditedTicket { get; set; }
```

Post handler:

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateTicket(ResponseModel response, int ticketId)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Model invalid");
        }

        return new JsonResult(new { success = true, message = "Ticket has been assigned!", errormessage = "Something went wrong, try again later" });
    }
```

Form HTML:

```
            <form id="edit_ticket" method="post">
                <label asp-for="EditedTicket.Description">Description</label>
                <input asp-for="EditedTicket.Description" name="EditedTicket.Description" class="form-control" />
                <input id="update-ticket" type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-white" value="Update" />
            </form>
```

Ajax call:

```
    //Button submit
    updateTicketBtn.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializedForm = $('#edit_ticket').serialize();
        console.log('This is serialized form: ', serializedForm);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/QAView/ProjectDetails?handler=UpdateTicket",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dateType: 'application/json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',   
            data: { 'response': serializedForm, 'ticketId': ticketId }
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log('Done!');
        })
    });
```

Comment: you post a form-data converted from the object format having properties of `response` & `ticketId`. Why do you want that to be mapped to the format having properties of `Description` & `Status`? That's too clear on why they are both null. Your `data` should be `serializedForm`.

Comment: BTW, please post your actual code instead of screenshots.

Comment: I want to pass two arguments - first, which is serialized form (`response` arg.) and second, which is number captured by javascript code - `tickedId`. That's why my `data` need to have two key-value pairs. `tickedId` value is passed correctly, the only problem is that `response` argument is still equal to `null`.

I'll replace these screenshots in a minute.

Comment: Posting questions on this forum always forces me to find solution for my own problems ASAP.
Problem was solved by adding correct `name` attributes for html form - I've changed value of this attribute from `EditedTicket.Description` to `Description`, without explicit referring to property name. Now my handler is receiving correct data.
Thank you!

Comment: that alone would not work if your data is still `{ 'response': serializedForm, 'ticketId': ticketId }`. I missed the point about the form element names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append your extra info (not included in `<form>`) like this:

```
var serializedForm = $('#edit_ticket').serialize();
serializedForm += "&ticketId=" + ticketId;
//...
//the posted data is changed to something like this:
data: serializedForm
```

For the model `ResponseModel`, because you bind it via the property `EditedTicket` you don't need it in the handler, like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateTicket(int ticketId){
     //access the property EditedTicket here
     //...
}
```

In case you want to bind it via an argument, you need a prefix setting like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateTicket([Bind(Prefix=nameof(EditedTicket))] ResponseModel response,
                                                 int ticketId){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this snippet of code, I hope it makes my solution a bit more cleaner.

Comment: @Tomitom see my updated answer for better solutions. If you update the `name` attribute ***manually***, it's not safe. You should use the `asp-for` in this case which means you need to stick to `EditedTicket.Description`.

Comment: It works perfect now! I removed `name` attributes from my form as well as binding for `EditedTicket` property. I think binding through handler argument is much better in my case. 
Thank you very much for simple and clean explanation.